# jsonb find a value in an array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

There is such a data structure:

```
Column "recipient" type jsonb

{
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "isDefault": true,
      "type": "MOBILE",
      "number": "3454654645"
    },
    {
      "isDefault": true,
      "type": "MOBILE",
      "number": "12423543645"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to write a search request by number. In the postgres documentation, I did not find a search by value in an array, only it is obtained by an index. It doesn't suit me

I made a query like this, it gets executed, but are there any other ways to search through an array?

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE recipient -> 'phoneNumbers' @> '[{"number":3454654645}]'
```

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty much the best way, yes.

If you have a (GIST) index on `recipient` the index would not be used by your condition. But the following could make use of such an index:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE recipient @> '["phoneNumbers": {"number":3454654645}]}'
```

If you are using Postgres 12 or later, you can also use a JSON path expression:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE recipient @@ '$.phoneNumbers[*].number == "12423543645"'
```

If you can't pass a JSON object to your query, you can use an EXISTS sub-select:

```
SELECT mt.*
FROM my_table mt
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(mt.recipient -> 'phoneNumbers') as x(element)
              WHERE x.element ->> 'number' = '3454654645')
```

The `'3454654645'` can be passed as a parameter to your query. This will never make use of an index though.

Comment: but is it possible to somehow iterate over the array?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve by "iterating". Both conditions will check in all array elements (thus implicitly it they "iterate")

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the matter is that I dynamically make substitution instead of "12423543645". Is it possible to make a query without quotation marks, since postgres interprets it as a string and does not allow the value to be dynamically substituted.

Comment: @hulxfp: but your values in the sample JSON are quoted as well, that's why you need to quote them in the search criteria also. But if you can't pass a "JSON value" to your query, you can use a sub-query